# Enumeration of few objects

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

If I want to enumerate few indicators that were measured, how can I do that without using a word "indicators"? My friend suggested "Were measured: professional identity, professional motivation, social personality values, leadership potential, etc.", but that doesn't sound right.

Comment: How about "measures"?

Comment: I think you'd better stick to "indicators". The NPs you mention (_professional identity, professional motivation, social personality values, leadership potential_) do not refer to actual phenomena, but rather to personal social judgements. Consequently, "measuring" them is a problematic term, and prejudging them as objectively measurable is misleading. Or it would be in respectable science or journalism, anyway. If this is advertising or public relations, then of course you can say anything you like any way you like.

Comment: How does one measure these intangibles?  Curious.

Comment: well, they characteristics were transfered to the numeric values in order to build a regression model. so, in some way they were measured. anyway, is it possible to describe what was done without using any particular word? does such thing as "inverse passive voice" exist?

Comment: You could call them predictors. you could also leave off any specific word but note that the things measured were measured by income, arrests, job performance, etc. or some other thing which is assumed to point to something like "leadership potential" or "social personality value".

Comment: What I mean is that I'm not sure how I should construct a sentence. I could use smith like "The indicators that were measured include:...", but is there any way to simplify this Construction? Something like "What was measured is", but more formal.

Comment: What's wrong with "indicators"? Why do you feel you need an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

If you replaced "Were measured" in your friend's suggested wording with something like "Several indicators were measured," I think you would have a serviceable passive-voice construction:

> Several indicators [or *factors* or *variables* or *criteria*] were measured [or *considered* or *quantified* or *assessed*]: professional identity, professional motivation, social personality values, leadership potential, etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about 'attributes' ? These things you mentioned sound like attributes of a personality.